# Jelly textarea tag required does not show

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jelly

Textbox

```
    <f:entry title="${%Name}" field="name">
        <f:textbox clazz="required" />
    </f:entry>
```

Textarea

```
    <f:entry title="${%Address}" field="address">
        <f:textarea />
    </f:entry>
```

However `clazz="required"` does not work for textarea, is there another tag that i am missing that has the same functionality as clazz required?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of the attribute `clazz="required"`.

But, I can suggest the another way of achieving the same:

Add the `doCheckVariableName` method (will be evaluated automatically) in the class where you are referring the `address` value.

```
public FormValidation doCheckAddress(@QueryParameter String value)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
       if (value.length() == 0)
           return FormValidation.error("Please set adress"); // just displays error message in the console when user do not enter any value in the address field. it doesn't stop jenkins build.
       return FormValidation.ok();
}
```

Reference:

1. Refer `FormValidation` section - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Basic+guide+to+Jelly+usage+in+Jenkins